# Accrued interest in the award of legal fees

Tags: united-states, litigation, legal-fees

If a party to a lawsuit is awarded legal fees, and their legal expenses were incurred over the course of several years of litigation, can the amount include interest on the expenses from the time they were incurred until the time they are awarded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The law isn't necessarily consistent across all states and even all different kinds of reasons that fees are awarded within a state, but the predominant practice is for interest to be awarded only post-judgment and not pre-judgment on attorneys' fees.